# Lucene Search with MultiThreads

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, lucene

I need to execute in my machine learning project >3000 queries in a index with 3GB size.

In order to speed up the performance I create 4 threads(I got 4 cores in my macbook pro) and I gave each one a part of the total queries(if I got N queries in total then each thread got n/4 queries).

I open my index via `FSDirectory.open(file)` and then I share the `IndexSearcher` to all the threads.

The problem is that I don't see any performance improvement neither cpu increase. I played with  different number of threads but still no change.

To save the whole index in RAM is not possible!

I saw on other threads that a solution was to open the index with read only but I use lucene 4.3 where write options are removed from the reader so no worries about read only mode anymore!

I am aware about [this page](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveSearchingSpeed) and the tips that give but looks quiet out of date.

So my question is how can I parallel the index search in order to improve the performance for real with lucene?

Below is an example code that i am using:

```
List<String> queryList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
for(int i=0;i<NUMBER_THREADS;i++){  
        List<String> querySubList = queryList.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);          
        QueryParser ngramIndexQueryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_43, "ngram", new KeywordAnalyzer());
        startWorker(querySubList, threads, date, ngramIndexQueryParser, nGramSearcher);
}


public static void startWorker(List<String> querySubList,  List<Thread> threads,QueryParser ngramIndexQueryParser,IndexSearcher nGramSearcher){
    NGramIndexSearch task = new NGramIndexSearch(queryList, ngramIndexQueryParser, nGramSearcher);
    Thread worker = new Thread(task);
    worker.start();
    threads.add(worker);
}


public class NGramIndexSearch implements Runnable {
    public NGramIndexSearch(List<String> queryList, String year,QueryParser queryParser, IndexSearcher searcher){
//initialization
    }
    public void run() {
      for(String q:queryList){
            Query query = queryParser.parse(queryText);
            TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(query, nrOfDocsToReturn);

      } 
    }
```

Comment: Could you show some code? Could be qn error when creating the threads..

Comment: Thanks! i update the question with example code..

Comment: And how do you calculate `fromIndex` and `toIndex`?

Comment: I calculate them correct mate. Its tested. Dont stuck with the fucntionality details, what about how i calculate the threads?

Comment: Did you find answer? What is the time difference between searching for 3000 queries and 750 queries in a single threaded way?